# Run-like pattern in candle chart

Tags: time-series, correlation, finance

To my untrained eye a pattern appears in this candle chart, where down-days (dark purple) tend to occur consecutively. I have a very basic understanding of statistics and R software, but it's been a while and I'd like to find the right search terms to get started with identifying / analyzing / confirming this pattern over longer series. Can you see a statistical phenomenon here or could you point me in the right direction, method or keyword?

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0):

"down-days (dark purple) tend to occur consecutively" can this be paraphrased as "after a dark purple it is more likely that a dark purple will follow than a white? Then just count after every dark purple whether a dark purple or a white follows. You can check, whether your counts are compatible with a 50%-chance using R's funktion binom.test(). If not, please specify your understanding of "occurs consecutively".